# Flipper implementation assambleRelease error

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, flipper

I am trying to assemble my app in Android Studio 4.2.1 (macOs Mojave) as assembleRelease
but i am getting this error

[Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.

> Could not find com.github.theGlenn:flipper-android-no-op:0.6.0]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoDoh.png)

here are my dependencies -

```
//Flipper
def flipperVersion = '0.94.1'
debugImplementation "com.facebook.flipper:flipper:$flipperVersion"
releaseImplementation "com.facebook.flipper:flipper-noop:$flipperVersion"
debugImplementation "com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:$flipperVersion"
debugImplementation "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.1"
// add this to no-op Flipper + SoLoader
releaseImplementation 'com.github.theGlenn:flipper-android-no-op:0.6.0'
```

and

```
       buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

    }
} allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

also added in manifest

```
   <activity android:name="com.facebook.flipper.android.diagnostics.FlipperDiagnosticActivity"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

while app:assembleDebug everything is fine

Could not find anything regarding this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should try this, it worked for me

```
releaseImplementation 'com.github.theGlenn.flipper-android-no-op:flipperandroidnoop:0.9.0'
releaseImplementation 'com.github.theGlenn.flipper-android-no-op:soloadernoop:0.9.0'
releaseImplementation 'com.github.theGlenn:flipper-android-no-op:0.9.0'
```